# Switching between UITextViews resets view Layout

Tags: swift, uiview, keyboard, textview, uitextfield

I implemented some functions to move the `UIView`, whenever a `TextField` or a `TextView` is tapped. The height for the `UIView` to move upwards is calculated depending how much the keyboard would overlap the active `TextField` or `TextView`. When I tap outside of the `TextField`, or -View the keyboard will be dismissed and the `View` will be resetted. Now everything is working fine, but when I switch from one `TextField` directly to another above (without dismissing the keyboard) it seems like the `UIView` will return to the initial position, instead of just keeping the shifted view (because the now active `TextView` would not be overlapped by the keyboard since it is above the former). It looks like some method is called to reset the view, resulting in the keyboard overlapping the upper `TextView`. Is there a way to suppress this behavior?

```
private func observeKeyboardNotification(){
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardShow), name: .UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardHide), name: .UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
}

var distanceOfKeyboardToTextView: CGFloat = 0
var activeTextElement: UIView?
var viewIsShifted = false

func keyboardShow(notification: NSNotification){
    findActiveTextField(subviews: self.view.subviews, textField : &activeTextElement)

    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue, let activeTextElement = activeTextElement, !viewIsShifted {

        let viewYPosition = (activeTextElement.superview?.convert(activeTextElement.frame.origin, to: nil).y)! + activeTextElement.frame.height
        let keyboardYPosition = view.frame.height - keyboardSize.height
        distanceOfKeyboardToTextView = viewYPosition - keyboardYPosition

        if distanceOfKeyboardToTextView > 0 {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5,
                           delay: 0,
                           usingSpringWithDamping: 1,
                           initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut,
                           animations: {
                            self.customView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.customView.frame.origin.y - self.distanceOfKeyboardToTextView, width: self.customView.frame.width, height: self.customView.frame.height)
                }, completion: nil)
            viewIsShifted = true
        }
    }
    activeTextElement = nil
}
func keyboardHide(){
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5,
                   delay: 0,
                   usingSpringWithDamping: 1,
                   initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut,
                   animations: {
                    self.customView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.customView.frame.origin.y + self.distanceOfKeyboardToTextView, width: self.customView.frame.width, height: self.customView.frame.height)
        }, completion: nil)
    viewIsShifted = false
    distanceOfKeyboardToTextView = 0
}

func findActiveTextField (subviews : [UIView], textField : inout UIView?) {
    guard textField == nil else { return }
    for view in subviews {
        if view.isFirstResponder {
            textField = view
            break
        }
        else if !view.subviews.isEmpty {
            findActiveTextField (subviews: view.subviews, textField: &textField)
        }
    }
}
```

**Update:**

After tapping from an active textfield directly onto another textfield, `keyboardShow` is call, but since the view is already shifed, `UIView.animate` will not be performed. However, the view is resetted like no keyboard would be displayed, but since the other textfield is active, the keyboard is visible.

I dismiss the keyboard using this extension:

```
extension UIViewController {

     //functions to hide the keyboard
     func hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround() {
         let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(UIViewController.dismissKeyboard))
         view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
     }
     func dismissKeyboard() {
         view.endEditing(true)
     }
 }
```

and in my ViewController:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()

     observeKeyboardNotification()
     self.hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround()

     ...
 }
```

Comment: Could you please explain this line of your code to me? `self.customView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.customView.frame.origin.y - self.distanceOfKeyboardToTextView, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.width)`. Why are you setting the height of the customView to the width of the view?!

Comment: This was incorrect probably due to some copy & paste action. I put the correct term in the animation closure, but that did not solve the error, though.